# Select data from 2 tables mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am new at stack-overflow. I have a question, please help me if anyone know .... I build a follower system in my web application where user can follow others and then he can see updates on his timeline. I have 2 tables

```
|     tbl_follow           |
|---------------------------
| id | follow | follow_by  |
| 01 | joe    | mark       |
----------------------------
```

And second table is:

```
|       timeline_tbl           |
|-------------------------------
| id | staus        | username |
| 01 | demo text    | joe      |
| 01 | demo text    | adem     |
--------------------------------
```

Now suppose login user is "mark". so mark will be able to see only "joe" status on his timeline because he followed him (see tbl_follow) "
Can someone please help me... and thanks in advance for your time and sorry for my bad english

Currently i used this code

```
$sql = ("select * from tbl_follow where username = 'mark' ");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $follow=$rows["follow"];
$asql = ("select * from timeline where username = '$follow' ");
$get = mysql_fetch_assoc($asql);
$status = $get['status'];
echo $status "<br>";
}
```

Comment: can you show the code you have already done ?

Comment: just give me a minute

Comment: The follow by should be an int type as a foreign key. Actually, I would suggest another table. You could have a user's table, a follow_relation table, and a timeline_tbl. Relation table could store the user ID and the following user ID.

Comment: you never executed the queries and you're mixing mysql APIs; that's why your code isn't working. And the connection api is unknown.

Comment: @crozet  please check update

Comment: my code is working ... it's a typing mistake. i want to execute in 1 query is there anyway? @Fred-ii- -ii

Comment: @joe you did successfully connect with `mysql_` and not `mysqli_` right? You were using a `mysqli_` function earlier `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: Plus, and again; you never executed any of those queries with `mysql_query()`. You say your code works; not the way you presented it in your question. `mysql_error()` right now, should be throwing you a whole bunch of errors.

Comment: you have to make a joint query : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: We would hope that the 'error' message would read "The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead..."

Comment: table structure didn't match with your code.cause *tbl_follow * has no username column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "select timeline_tbl.* from tbl_follow JOIN timeline_tbl ON timeline_tbl.username =  tbl_follow.follow where follow_by = 'mark' "

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found";
    exit;
}


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["staus"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.* 
from timeline_tbl t
join tbl_follow f on f.username = t.follow
where t.follow = 'mark'
```

It will return all records which are followers of MARK.